# Hornetq - connect 1 queue to multiple addresses?

Tags: hornetq

Im using HornetQ as an embedded server. I am able to create multiple queues and have them bound to a single address. This works well and I can send a message to a single address and have it consumed by multiple queues. I've another business need to have multiple addresses sending messages to a single queue. The use case would be if you think of the queue as a user who is "subscribed" to multiple things happening in the system. Meaning that different events will post to different addresses and those messages will go to a users personal queue if he subscribed to them. Is this possible? 
The only way I could think of it was to set up diverts. Wondering If there is a better way. Diverts work because I divert the messages on multiple addresses to a single unique address per user which maps to the queue. Btw; I'm using the CORE API

Answer (score 2):

Wildcard queues?

http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.5.Final/user-manual/en/html_single/index.html#wildcard-routing

Divert is a good option as well